# Researchkit limit multichoice

Tags: ios, swift, researchkit

I have the following scenario: user have 10 choices presented and can pick only TWO. Now, in HTML it was easy with *javascript* to limit user's choice on two, but is there a way to do so in ResearchKit multichoice?

If you can give me any hint, tip, or demo code (preferably in Swift) I'd appreciate.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be added in future. https://github.com/ResearchKit/ResearchKit/issues/496

For now use isAnswerValid to validate answer.